# Using Firebase Analytics inside our android SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We're building SDK for Android apps which hopefully be used inside many android apps.

We need analytics both for ourselves and for the companies who would implement our SDK.

Does it make sense to implement firebase analytics inside our SDK in order to achieve this requirements? 
(I know that it works with big query so I thought I might be able to gain lots of value from it.)
Is it even possible? (because of the JSON needed for the hosting app)

If it does make sense, what I really need is a list of pros and cons for using it in this scenario.

Comment: Good question.
Also, will this use of Firebase limit in any way the app implementing the sdk? 
There are a lot of issues here, hope people with the relevant experience will show up :-)

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do such a thing as of now.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) within your app, then track who uses your SDK by [logging a custom event and parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) or any other information that you need.

Note that custom parameters are not directly displayed in your Analytics reports, however you can [link your app to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) to see these data.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this directly answers my question.  I'm more interested if it makes sense + if theres a technical option to use it inside an sdk that would be implemented inside other app. +Please note that I'm aware of big query, as stated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is not possible.

There is an issue created for this on Github.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/66

**Initialize FirebaseApp without google-services.json**

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setApplicationId(applicationID) // Required for Analytics.
                    .setApiKey(apiKey) // Required for Auth.
                    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options);

<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

But the replies says as below:

> Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) doesn't support dynamic
> initialization. Our engineers are checking the possible solutions to
> support this. It's just that we still haven't found a definite
> timeline as to when (or if) this will be available. GA4F will not work
> without the google-services.json file (or Gradle on your end). Even
> though you can initialize the FirebaseApp dynamically through code,
> GA4F will not recognize this and will only result in the error message
> you are seeing. The scenario you are getting is only specific to
> Google Analytics for Firebase. However, you can still use other
> products like Firestore, Realtime Database, Storage even if you are
> not using Gradle plugin.